# Prevent nested frameworks from being visible to the containing app

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos, frameworks

Consider this hierarchy of app & nested frameworks:

```
- App
  |- Logic.framework
     |- Persistence.framework
```

In the example above we have to make types in `Persistence.framework` public in order for them to be visible to `Logic.framework`, however this opens them up to being accessible from the App.

Is it possible, in Swift, to import nested frameworks that cannot be seen to the containing app? I know that the testing targets can use the `@testable` keyword to achieve something similar but was wondering if there is any way to do this for the app.